# Define functions on Geographic regions

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, geography, geographics

Let's plot a parametric function $(x_s(u,v), \:y_s(u,v))$ on some $uv$ domain as shown below  with an annulus as example.

```
    xs[u_, v_] := (1/4 - I/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*(-Erf[(1/2 + I/2)*u] + Erf[(1/2 + 
   I/2)*(u - I*v)] - Erfi[(1/2 + I/2)*u] + Erfi[(1/2 + I/2)*(u + I*v)]);

    ys[u_, v_] := (1/4 + I/4)*Sqrt[Pi]*(-Erf[(1/2 + I/2)*u] + Erf[(1/2 + 
  I/2)*(u - I*v)] + Erfi[(1/2 + I/2)*u] - Erfi[(1/2 + I/2)*(u + I*v)]); 

  ParametricPlot[{{xs[u, v], ys[u, v]}}, Element[{u, v}, Annulus[{1, 1}, {0.5, 1}]]]
```

Now, I wish to take as domain, instead of an annulus, some geographical region, for instance Portugal. Up to now I've learned to plot such regions using

```
 GeoGraphics[{Polygon[Entity["Country", "Portugal"]]}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

but how to convert that plot into a mathematical set where I could evaluate `ParametricPlot` ?

Comment: So, the $u$ and $v$ in your function would be latitude and longitude?

Comment: @J.M. True (for simplicity). Also, I would place the object on the first quadrant to have $u>0$ and $v>0$.

Comment: You have a first example in the book : Dauphiné A. Geographical Models with Mathematica, ISTE Press Elsevier, 2017, pages 231-232

Comment: @Dauphine Nice. I'm gonna take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Dauphine I checked it and that's not exactly what I'm looking for. That's simply a superposition, what I need to do is to take the domain and map it through a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible method:

Get the polygon you want to handle as a geo region:

```
georegion = Entity["Country", "Portugal"]["Polygon"]
```

You need to choose a geo projection to give meaning to the {u, v} pairs. If you need them to be {lon, lat} then choose "Equirectangular", but perhaps you need to start with "Mercator" coordinates, or "Mollweide" coordinates. Let us choose "Mercator". Discretize the result:

```
region = DiscretizeRegion[GeoGridPosition[georegion, "Mercator"]]
```

Now you can perform a computation (I use something simpler than your function):

```
map = ParametricPlot[{{u - v + 40, u + v}}, Element[{u, v}, region], PlotStyle -> Green]
```

Show both maps together (note that I use the same projection, for consistency of interpretation):

```
Show[GeoGraphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Red], georegion}, GeoProjection -> "Mercator", GeoBackground -> "VectorMonochrome"], map, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Great !! That's a simple, nice solution. Thank you so much.